# How to Iterate through a JSON Array in Vibe.D?

Tags: d, vibed

What's the correct way, using the Vibe.D library, to iterate through a Json array?

I have tried this, but it gives me compile errors:

```
foreach(string index, Json value; configuration["array1"]) {}
```

This is the error:

```
Error: opApply() function for Json must return an int
```

Full code:

```
foreach(int index, Json pluginToLoad; configuration["PluginsToLoad"]) {
    import std.conv;
    logInfo(to!string(index));
    logInfo(pluginToLoad.get!string);
    logInfo("---");
}
```

Comment: looks like the vibe.d guys didn't implement opApply - I'd file this as a bug with them. I don't know the right way to do it though, I'm not a vibed user :(

Comment: Can you show a full example? As I think your code should work.
This page has an example using foreach on a `Json` object.
http://vibed.org/api/vibe.data.json/

Comment: @yaz That's what my code is based of basically. `configuration` is an object of type Json. I don't have access to my code atm but I'll give it as soon as possible. (Different computer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `index` must be of integer type - this is pretty much what error message says. JSON array is always plain array, associative ones are called JSON objects.

Example:

```
foreach (size_t index, Json value; configuration["array1"]) {}
```

or simply

```
foreach (index, value; configuration["array1"]) {} // type inference
```

Update: changed `int` to `size_t` to match actual opApply signature

Comment: I tried that but it won't allow me to set the value to string in that case.

Comment: `Error: cannot uniquely infer foreach argument types`

Comment: Does this mean `opApply` isn't implemented properly? I've Googled the problem and `opApply` seems to be a popular problem. Adam D. Ruppe also suggested something similar.

Comment: I have had a look at JSON source code and probably inference does not work simply because there are too many opApply overloads (http://vibed.org/api/vibe.data.json/Json.opApply) , so compiler can't guess one to use.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, using a ulong works. I'm guessing this is a bug?

```
foreach(ulong index, Json pluginToLoad; configuration["PluginsToLoad"])
```

Comment: No, it matches opApply signature in JSON module (signed and unsigned are not that interchangeable afaik)